# Sed command with apostrophe

Tags: sed

```
sed -e 's/cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'/cluster_name: 'Test Cluster1'/'
```

I have this error message:

```
  sed: -e expression, char 20: unterminated `s' command
```

Please, how can i correct the sed command ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ sed -e "s/cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'/cluster_name: 'Test Cluster1'/"
```

or

```
sed -e 's/cluster_name: '\''Test Cluster'\'\/cluster_name:' '\'Test' 'Cluster1\'/
```

The one with all single quotes was more difficult to construct without this program to help, If you want some help getting the command correct, there is a C program you can use

```
$ cat w.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int i = 0;
        while (argv[i]) {
                printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
                i++;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I am testing from cygwin, but any *nix shell should be the same

You see this works

```
$ ./w sed -e "s/cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'/cluster_name: 'Test Clust
er1'/"
argv[0] = F:\blah\w.exe
argv[1] = sed
argv[2] = -e
argv[3] = s/cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'/cluster_name: 'Test Cluster1'/


$
```

Whereas if you try the one from suspectus

```
sed -e 's/cluster_name: \'Test Cluster\'/cluster_name: \'Test Cluster1\'/'
```

You can use the program to find the fault in it

His one doesn't even execute

```
$ ./w  sed -e 's/cluster_name: \'Test Cluster\'/cluster_name: \'Test C
luster1\'/'
>CTRL-C
```

Because it has a missing single quote

> $ ./w  'fgg
>   >

among perhaps other problems.

And if you look at suspectus's one, it fails even near the beginning, it breaks on the space

```
$ ./w  sed -e 's/cluster_name: \'Test Clu
argv[0] = f:\blah\w.exe
argv[1] = sed
argv[2] = -e
argv[3] = s/cluster_name: \Test
argv[4] = Clu
```

This one works

```
$ ./w  sed -e 's/cluster_name: '\''Test Cluster'\'\/cluster_name:' '\'
Test' 'Cluster1\'/
argv[0] = F:\blah\w.exe
argv[1] = sed
argv[2] = -e
argv[3] = s/cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'/cluster_name: 'Test Cluster1'/
```

When you put it together you can try adding a space and a character, and then you see whether your quote mode is on or off. If it's off then if you want to escape a single quote then use \'  If it's on then turn it off with '  then do \'  If you lose track wther it's on or off then add a space, see if it makes a new parameter or not.

Comment: @researcher  Even if you don't know C.  if you can compile that C program and understand how to use it,  it will help you a lot if you often run into problems re escaping things on the command line.  All these programs like sed for example, are C programs and that little C program shows you how they would see the parameters

Answer (score 2):

You would need to escape the single quotes in the sed `s` command:

```
sed -e 's/cluster_name: '\''Test Cluster'\''/cluster_name: '\''Test Cluster1'\''/'
```

Editing single quotes is often tricky. Whereever there is a single quote in the string you replace with `'\''` I will try to explain how this works - feel free anyone to improve on this!

`'\''` - first quote ends sed string and what follows is parsed by the shell. The backslash renders the character that follows as a simple character (and not a meta-character). The final quote then ends the bash interpreted section and what follows is parsed by `sed`.

Comment: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ` ' '

Comment: Editing single quotes is a pain! I've updated answer.

Comment: Your still fails  `$ echo abc|sed -e 's/cluster_name: '\''Test Cluster'\''/cluster_name:
\'Test Cluster1\'/'
>CTRL-C`   Try my one

Comment: I missed out the extra meta stuff on the replacement string. Now edited.

Comment: @suspectus well you should've tested it the first time round instead of the third time round!

Comment: Agreed. Time is the ultimate commodity and I have been starved of it at work today!